# Как добавить блок с кодом на страницу wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

У меня есть таблица, как можно добавлять поле в редакторе страницы, и изменять ссылки в новом поле? Просто добавить запись нельзя тк добавление надо делать на главной странице. Подскажите, варианты что можно посмотреть или почитать чтобы решить эту задачу

Comment: Используйте плагин Advanced Custom Fields (ACF).

Comment: @KAGGDesign можете пожалуйста прикрепить маленький пример использования?

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/plugin/acf/dobavlenie-polej-k-opredelennoj-rubrike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://uk.wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/ - простое и быстрое решение, на каме есть статья с базовым функционалом (https://wp-kama.ru/plugin/acf)